# Finding integral of $\sin x$ by definition.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

Dividing given interval into n equal parts and for every interval taking ϵ as an midpoint of an interval find integral sum of a function and compute it.

$y=\sin x$  $x \in[0,\pi]$

$\triangle x_i= \frac{\pi}{n}i$

$\epsilon_i= \frac{0+\frac{\pi}{n}i+0+\frac{\pi}{n}(i+1)}{2} = \frac{2i+1}{2n}\pi$

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\sin\left(\frac{(2i+1)\pi}{2n}\right)\cdot\frac{\pi}{n} = \frac{\pi}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\sin\left(\frac{(2i+1)\pi}{2n}\right)$$
from here I can't continue

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2048590/how-do-we-know-what-the-integral-of-sin-x-is

Comment: @Mark No because at that question $\epsilon$ is chosen as a right endpoint we need midpoint.

Comment: Since the function is integrable, you can choose any points. Not sure if you can easily compute it specifically with midpoints.

Comment: @Mark Yes I know my textbook says choose midpoints.

Comment: This should answer your question, and has a wide variety of great proofs: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17966/how-can-we-sum-up-sin-and-cos-series-when-the-angles-are-in-arithmetic-pro

Comment: @TomKern In that post I am getting $S \times \sin\frac{d}{2}$ = $\frac{1}{2}$ ($cos(a-\frac{d}{2}) - cos(a+\frac{d(2n+1)}{2})$

Comment: but it should be $\sin(n \times \frac{d}{2})\ \times \sin\biggl( \frac{2  a + (n-1)\cdot d}{2}\biggr)$